# Which type of binding does PL/SQL use?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, binding

I came across the following question.

**PL/SQL uses which of the following**

- (A) No Binding
- (B) Early Binding
- (C) Late Binding
- (D) Deferred Binding

But could not find any satisfying answers.

Can anybody give an explanation for this?

Comment: These aren't absolute term. We'd probably need some more context. But most likely, *early binding* is the correct answer as PL/SQL is a mostly static, type-safe language.

Comment: The only exception is probably the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement, which is more of a *late binding*. But it's a really special case like *eval* in Javascript.

Comment: Multiple-choice questions expect a single answer, so (assuming the question and its answers are 100% accurate) the answer can't be that PL/SQL uses Early Binding as well as Late Binding. Of course, the assumption that the question and answers are 100% correct is a big assumptions (and sometimes wrong, too).

Answer (score 15):

> (E) All of the Above

This is a ridiculous multiple choice question.  The terms early, late, and deferred binding are ambiguous.  And PL/SQL can be run in many different ways, including in SQL.

Here are my (arguably incorrect) definitions of the choices:

1. No binding - Variables have no types.
2. Early Binding - Variable types are fixed at compile time.
3. Late Binding - Variable types are flexible and may be set at run time.
4. Deferred Binding - Multiple variables types are defined at compile time, but only one of them is chosen at run time.

Now we have to match those choices to different PL/SQL contexts: static SQL and PL/SQL, empty anonymous blocks, remote procedures, dynamic SQL and PL/SQL, adaptive cursor sharing, `FILTER` operations, object-oriented PL/SQL, ANY* types, and I'm probably missing some more.

**(A) No binding**

An empty anonymous block doesn't have any variables so nothing is bound.  I'm not sure if this really fits the definition of no binding, it seems kind of like an edge case.  In some languages there is always an object and something must always be bound, but not in PL/SQL.

**(B) Early Binding**

Regular SQL and PL/SQL use early binding - variables are given a type and they must stick to it.  Type mismatches will either throw a compiler error or require implicit conversion.

Remote procedure calls with `REMOTE_DEPENDENCIES_MODE` set to "TIMESTAMP" is arguably early binding.  The timestamp is set at compile time when everything is checked.  It *is* still checked at run time, but it's a simple and fast check.

**(C) Late Binding**

Dynamic SQL and PL/SQL use late binding because the code is not even compiled until run time.  This applies both to `DBMS_SQL` and `execute immediate`.

Object-Oriented PL/SQL uses late binding.  The type is set at compile time but a different subtype may be used at run time.

ANYTYPE, ANYDATA, and ANYDATASET also use late binding since they can be created at run time, or retrieved and executed at run time.

Remote procedure calls with `REMOTE_DEPENDENCIES_MODE` set to "SIGNATURE" is arguably late binding.  The signature is checked at both compile time and run time, and allows for a tiny bit of flexibility in types.

**(D) Deferred Binding**

Some Oracle SQL features create multiple code paths but only execute one of them.  Adaptive cursor sharing and `FILTER` operations will create multiple ways to run the same SQL statement, and the appropriate version is chosen at run time.

---

**Invoker's Rights and Definer's Rights**

Invoker's rights and definer's rights also complicate this question.  But I think that ultimately they don't make a difference, and that both of them are still early binding.  The compiler still *decides* the type at compile time.  Although you can use invoker's rights to stealthily change a type at run time it will only generate an error because it doesn't match the expected type.

For example, let's say there are two schemas that have the same table and column names, but different types:

```
create table user1.test_table(a number);
insert into suer1.test_table values(1);

create table user2.test_table(a date);
insert into user2.test_table values(sysdate);
```

If you create this function on USER1 it *looks* like the type of `V_VALUE` is dynamic and can change with the user.

```
create or replace function user1.test_function return varchar2 authid current_user is
    v_value test_table.a%type;
begin
    select a into v_value from test_table;
    return to_char(v_value);
end;
/
```

The code compiles using the types from `USER1` and works fine when run by USER1.  However, when USER2 runs it this error is generated: `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE`.

This leads me to believe that invoker's and definer's rights do not affect the binding.  They both use early binding in static SQL and PL/SQL.

Comment: Your very good answer might be improved by adding "invoker rights" and how they affect binding.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak - perhaps a discussion of "invoker rights" in this context is good, to pre-empt objections like "invoker rights may change the answer." However, such objections would be incorrect (as Jon discussed in what he added). Invoker rights may change the data that the runtime uses, but the binding (the identification of data types and inclusion of proper memory allocation in whatever machine code is generated) DOES NOT CHANGE. So invoker rights doesn't have any effect on the kind of binding.

Comment: I was just thinking about invoker rights too - very nicely summed up :)

Answer (score 10):

You can find the answer in a very very old documentation related to Oracle 8:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58236/05_ora.htm

> **Efficiency versus Flexibility**
>
> Before a PL/SQL program can be executed, it must be compiled. The
>   PL/SQL compiler resolves references to Oracle schema objects by
>   looking up their definitions in the data dictionary. Then, the
>   compiler assigns storage addresses to program variables that will hold
>   Oracle data so that Oracle can look up the addresses at run time. This
>   process is called binding.
>
> How a database language implements binding affects runtime efficiency
>   and flexibility. Binding at compile time, called static or early
>   binding, increases efficiency because the definitions of schema
>   objects are looked up then, not at run time. On the other hand,
>   binding at run time, called dynamic or late binding, increases
>   flexibility because the definitions of schema objects can remain
>   unknown until then.
>
> Designed primarily for high-speed transaction processing, PL/SQL
>   increases efficiency by bundling SQL statements and avoiding runtime
>   compilation. Unlike SQL, which is compiled and executed
>   statement-by-statement at run time (late binding), **PL/SQL is processed
>   into machine-readable p-code at compile time (early binding)**. At run
>   time, the PL/SQL engine simply executes the p-code.

But Oracle in subsequent versions removed the whole chapter **Interaction with Oracle** from the documentation.

So, according to the above the answer is: **(B) Early Binding** - for sure for Oracle version 8, and perhaps in futher versions.

Comment: Oracle support document 1008453.6, last updated by Oracle on 04-OCT-2016 reiterates this: _PL/SQL uses static or early binding. This means that binding is done at compile time which increases efficiency because the definitions of database objects are looked up at compile time, rather than at run time._  As other's have pointed out, there are many exceptions, but early binding is the way basic PL/SQL seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

**edit**: I just rephrased the answer to get to the point a bit quicker.

**short answer**

- **PL uses early binding and sometimes late binding** (e.g. is late when using the Object-oriented capabilities of PL/SQL, and the polymorphism they feature)
- **SQL uses deferred binding**: the resolution of symbols (tables names, columns, etc) happens during a postponed compilation that occurs at runtime: this step involves  parsing and compiling sql text into executable instructions (the "execution plan")

The deferred binding is at the core of the SQL engine and makes it extremely adaptable to changing distribution of data; it is a core feature that everybody should be aware of, so my best guess is that the question asked for it, unless by "PL/SQL" they meant "PL" (as often Oracle docs do).

The example below hopefully makes the point immediately clear.  We have two users ("demo" and "scott") that own a table and a procedure each, with the same names.

```
demo
  invoked_proc
  x_table

scott
  invoked_proc
  x_table
```

If we create the procedure below in the schema "demo", this is how Oracle would resolve the symbols during compilation and during execution

```
compilation
  "invoked_proc": demo.invoked_proc
  "x_table": demo.x_table

execution when logged as "demo": the same

execution when logged as "scott"
  "invoked_proc": demo.invoked_proc <- resolves as per compilation
  "x_table": scott.x_table <- resolved differently
```

Here is the procedure, and the fact that we are using invoker's rights is not fundamental, it is just making the matter more evident:

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE demo.invoker_proc
AUTHID CURRENT_USER 
IS
n number := 1;
BEGIN

   invoked_proc();

   select id into n
   from X_TABLE where id = n;

END;
/
```

**Long answer**

All types of binding are involved (b, c, d). Amongst those, the *deferred binding* is probably the most remarkable, so if they asked to choose just one answer, I'd definitively go for "d" (deferred binding) when speaking of SQL, and "b" (early binding) when dealing with PL.

We probably should start by saying that the terminology is important, and that possibly the answer provided by [krokodilko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2568341/krokodilko) is the most authoritative given the docs it points at (even if that reference is potentially obsolete).

However I firmly believe the point of the whole matter is that in Oracle, the PL engine and the SQL engine are almost completely set apart and resolve the names in totally different ways. While the former usually involves some form of early or late binding (mostly, early binding), the latter always imply deferred binding: SQL statements are "compiled" into executable plans when executed, not at compile time. The semantic resolution of the symbols is deferred until when the query is run, so the names are resolved according to the current context (primarily, the current user). This is also the type of binding used when issuing an `execute immediate` statement, `dbms_sql`, or `dbms_job.submit` invoked with `NO_PARSE = true`.

When Oracle encounters the text of an **SQL statement**, even when is part of a compiled PL unit (procedure, function, trigger...), it performs a **syntactic analysis** of its symbols first, **then a semantic analysis** and finally "compiles" the execution plan (determines the procedural steps of the algorithm that will actually resolve the query).

Depending on the situation it can skip part of this analysis: however all of this **fundamentally happens at runtime**, not at compile time. This allows the engine to adapt, for instance to the latest statistics it has gathered from the data (this is what the Cost Based Optimizer strives to do), and is fundamentally different from what the Rule Based Optimizer used to do in earlier versions (queries where "compiled" at compile time, and the algorithm was know in advance and fixed until the next re-compilation; ).

The only pre-baked product of the compilation of a PL unit is the **resolution of its direct dependencies, which occurs at compile time** (information which is stored in the DIANA code) and enables the engine to detect when it is time to re-compile a PL unit due to external changes (for instance, changes in the structure of a table mentioned in an SQL statement). Note that this preemptive mechanism falls short when using invoker's right, precisely because Oracle cannot be aware of what the name will reference later,, during the execution.

All of this is dramatically evident when we use invoker rights to run a procedure.
Consider the aforementioned case, in which two users have a procedure and a table on their respective schemas, named equal (the tables happens to be identical except that scott's table has an index on it)

```
CONNECT demo/demo

CREATE PROCEDURE invoked_proc IS
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('invoked_proc owned by demo');
END;
/
GRANT execute on invoked_proc to public;

create table X_TABLE (id number);
insert into x_table values(1);
commit;


CONNECT scott/tiger

CREATE PROCEDURE invoked_proc IS
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('invoked_proc owned by scott');
END;
/


create table X_TABLE (id number);
create index X_INDEX ON X_TABLE(id);
insert into x_table values(1);
commit;
```

and consider what happens when you compile a third procedure (on a single schema) that references those names and which is executed with invoker's rights:

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE invoker_proc
AUTHID CURRENT_USER 
IS
n number := 1;
BEGIN

   invoked_proc();

   select id into n
   from X_TABLE where id = n;

END;
/
```

What can we say about the symbols that have been resolved by the compiler?
We can quickly infer them by looking at the dependencies of `INVOKER_PROC`:

```
select owner, name,
referenced_owner, referenced_name
from dba_dependencies
where name = 'INVOKER_PROC';


OWNER   NAME          REFERENCED_OWNER   REFERENCED_NAME
------- ------------- ------------------ -----------------
DEMO    INVOKER_PROC  DEMO               X_TABLE
DEMO    INVOKER_PROC  DEMO               INVOKED_PROC
```

So, both the procedure and the table identified by the compiler belong to DEMO, the user where the procedures belongs.
As for the plan that underlies the sql query, nothing has been determined yet:

```
Select substr(sql_text,1,40),
sql_id,
plan_hash_value,
parsing_schema_name,
child_number
from v$sql
where sql_text like '%X_TABLE%'
;

no relevant records found...
```

However, things start to get different when the sql engine is actually invoked, which doesn't happen until runtime.

```
connect demo/demo

EXEC demo.invoker_proc

> invoked_proc owned by demo
```

and looking at the plans we see that a new plan is around

```
Select substr(sql_text,1,40),
sql_id,
plan_hash_value,
parsing_schema_name,
child_number
from v$sql
where sql_text like '%X_TABLE%'
;


SUBSTR(SQL_TEXT,1,40)                  SQL_ID        PLAN_HASH_VALUE PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME CHILD_NUMBER 
-------------------------------------- ------------- --------------- ------------------- ------------ 
SELECT ID FROM X_TABLE WHERE ID = :B1  01a77qj300y18      1220025608 DEMO                           0
```

If we run the same procedure from scott's perspective and look at the plans, we see that the same `invoked_proc` has been called, the one owned by DEMO (it outputs "`invoked_proc owned by demo`").
So **the name resolution of the PL part carried during the compilation still holds true (early binding)**. The same is not quite true for the SQL part:

```
connect scott/tiger

EXEC demo.invoker_proc;

> invoked_proc owned by demo


SUBSTR(SQL_TEXT,1,40)                  SQL_ID        PLAN_HASH_VALUE PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME CHILD_NUMBER 
-------------------------------------- ------------- --------------- ------------------- ------------ 
SELECT ID FROM X_TABLE WHERE ID = :B1  01a77qj300y18      1220025608 DEMO                           0 
SELECT ID FROM X_TABLE WHERE ID = :B1  01a77qj300y18      3707869577 SCOTT                          1
```

We see that it has created another plan for the new query, with a different `child_number`. **The second plan references the other table, other than the one determined during compilation (deferred binding)**. This is confirmed if we look at the content of the plans; the first plan involves a plain table, on which only a full scan can be performed:

```
select plan_table_output
from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(
    SQL_ID => '01a77qj300y18'
    ,CURSOR_CHILD_NO =>  0
    ));


SQL_ID  01a77qj300y18, child number 0
-------------------------------------
SELECT ID FROM X_TABLE WHERE ID = :B1

Plan hash value: 1220025608

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |         |       |       |     4 (100)|          |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| X_TABLE |     1 |    13 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

while the second table, which offers an index, allows Oracle to get a better code path (an index range scan in this case)

```
select plan_table_output
from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(
    SQL_ID => '01a77qj300y18'
    ,CURSOR_CHILD_NO =>  1
    ));

SQL_ID  01a77qj300y18, child number 1
-------------------------------------
SELECT ID FROM X_TABLE WHERE ID = :B1

Plan hash value: 3707869577

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |         |       |       |     1 (100)|          |
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| X_INDEX |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The takeaway is that **PL usually involves early or late binding, while SQL always is deferred**.

There are further considerations that can come into play, like the usage of `BASELINES` (precompiled plans that are permanently stored and can be choosen or not depending on what the optimizer believes cheaper) or `ADAPTIVE CURSORS` (alternative plans stored in the library pool that are chosen at runtime); and they involve slightly different concepts. However, given the lack of consensus on the term "deferred binding", possibly all of them can be considered part of the "deferred binding thing" (I am curious to know the opinion of who wrote the original quiz).

For instance this is not in contrast with what I see in .NET: deferred binding seems to be a topic loosely related to code that is reflexively generated and compiled during runtime. While GWT claims to use "deferred binding"; meaning by that: alternative code segments are compiled and only one is chosen at runtime (to quote them "In essence, deferred binding is the GWT answer to Java reflection", see [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html))

Comment: Yes, I agree, definitively too long and unreadable. The question is interesting and challenging, and has given rise to good answers by competent people. However I believe that the main point was generally missed, and to make up for that I ended up with an endless explanation. When I get the chance I'll tidy up my answer and, most importantly, make it shorter.

Answer (score 2):

From the query posted, I understand that using which binding type PL/SQL is developed in general. In that case option **(B) Early Binding** is the answer as oracle.

Further,

1. PL - Stored Procedures - Early Binding.
2. PL - Remote Procedures - Late Binding.
3. Dynamic SQL - Late Binding.

Answer (score 0):

Before a PL/SQL program can be executed, it must be compiled. The PL/SQL compiler resolves references to Oracle objects by looking up their definitions in the data dictionary. Then, the compiler assigns storage addresses to program variables that will hold Oracle data so that Oracle can look up the addresses at run time. This process is called **binding**.

***How a database language implements binding, affect run-time efficiency and flexibility?***

Binding at compile time, called static or early binding, increases efficiency because the definitions of database objects are looked up then, not at run time.

On the other hand, binding at run time, called dynamic or late binding, increases flexibility because the definitions of database objects can remain unknown until then.

Answer (score 0):

Its **(B) Early Binding** which is used at **compile time** and **(C) Late Binding** which is used at **run time**.